# Where can I learn more about Conceptual Data Model?

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema, conceptual-model

Where can I learn more about Conceptual Data Model? I have to create a schema based on the convention in the image below.

[image]

I don't understand  the "bubble" (or relationship) between the two entities. What should be the name of a relationship (verb, nom, etc.)?

Is there books or websites which cover this data modelisation theory? What is the name of those diagram? I googled as much as I can around "Conceptual Data Model" and I didn't find anything similar to the image above.

Thanks for the help.

P.S. I will be using Open ModelSphere "Conceptual Data Model".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try learning the Entity Relationship Model : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model

And also the Unified Modeling Language : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language

Here is one book by Korth: http://www.db-book.com/ for starting DBMS. Have a look at the ER-Model chapter.

For UML have a look at : [http://www.amazon.com/UML-Distilled-Standard-Modeling-Language/dp/020165783X?tag=particculturf-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020165783X)